# Recover broken VM on Citrix XenServer

Tags: mysql, virtualization, xenserver, citrix

I have accidentally upgraded the hard drive on my XenServer machine, and didn't remember to transfer my database VM. All machines has been restored, but this one machine. All I have are 2 virtual disks, and I need to recover my mysql files inside. SR has been recognized, and attached, but I can't make it to boot from the vdi. The Xen server gave me blank screen, not even the black console screen, but a blank white screen without console.

Please help.. I really need those files, and I don't care how. Only those mysql files.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about attaching the virtual disks to another guest and pulling the files off that way?